# Parse / Facebook -> Session does not match current stored session

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

Using Parse backend on iOS, researched all of the answers on the parse website, they're all from 2+ years ago.

I keep getting:

"Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons."

Session is invalidated.  Fine.  I understand.  I want a new token.

Problem is, I've no idea how to create a new session using Parse and can't find it anywhere on their website.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is ridiculous.  For anyone else in the future, this is not a proper fix, but something that I did to make it work:

System Settings -> Facebook -> Delete account.

Everything then works as normal BUT, this isn't a proper fix.  I've asked the developers of Parse so will post a solution when I find one.